# Need a more useful error than "Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(...)"

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, angular

I'm developing with Angular 2 and C#.net, though I've seen this error all over Google and S/O with other platforms. I could swear I once came across a solution allowing for a more useful console error by temporarily adjusting some code, but could never find it again.

Here's the pervasive catch-all error I see every day:

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(...)

If I expand it the contents are like snowflakes: every one is unique but they tell you nothing about where they came from.

Back when I got a more useful error I think I had to either edit something in my Global.asax or my systemjs.config.js but I really can't remember.

All I want for Christmas is a more useful error message. Just for kicks here are the contents of my systemjs.config.js and Global.asax:

***systemjs.config.js***

```
(function (global) {

    var getUrl = window.location;
    var baseUrl = getUrl.protocol + '//' + getUrl.host + '/' + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1] + '/';

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': baseUrl + 'app', // 'dist',

        '@angular': baseUrl + 'Scripts/lib_node/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': baseUrl + 'Scripts/lib_node/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs': baseUrl + 'Scripts/lib_node/rxjs'
    };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade'
  ];

  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

  // No umd for router yet
  packages['@angular/router'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

***Global.asax***

```
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        private const string RootUrl = "~/Home/Index";
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var path = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

            // To allow access to api via url:
            var isApi = path.StartsWith("/CW/api", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            // To allow direct access to my account controller:
            var isAccount = path.StartsWith("/CW/account", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (isApi || isAccount)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Context.Server.MapPath(path)))
                Context.RewritePath(RootUrl);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
*One thing that works most of the time though not all is to temporarily comment out my Application_BeginRequest() since that seems to occasionally feed HTML to the browser when it expects JS... Not the best solution but a useful work-around.*

Comment: That error is a JS error. It does not have anything to do with the back end code

Comment: Where specifically does this error happen?  I'd expect to see this when the browser is attempting to interpret JavaScript code but encounters HTML code.  "Just for kicks" doesn't help much, we need to know what *actually* produces the error.

Comment: Your're both missing the point. This error is produced in many places for many reasons. I'm trying to get a more detailed error message. One thing that often works is to comment out my Application_BeginRequest so @David's statement makes some sense.

Comment: Most of the times that I see this error come up is when there's a 404 error page being returned when I am expecting a js file or json response.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, what can help you at this level is the request that is associated with the error message.

For example:

> angular2-polyfills.js:1243 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/@angular/core Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/boot.js

This means that you got a 404 error when trying to load http://localhost:3000/angular2/angular2. The payload of the 404 is HTML and not JS, so this can't be parsed.

This error is triggered by the line:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

SystemJS executes the request http://localhost:3000/angular2/angular2 to load the module according to its configuration (file `systemjs.config.js`).

See this article for more details:

- https://medium.com/@ttemplier/common-errors-you-can-encounter-when-angular2-applications-b875c2a5d5c5#.yqmz5hgg2

Comment: If I'm reading you right you're suggesting I look at the network activity for the request? I'll have to test that next time I see it. If you're saying to look at the error itself, no good. It always just says "Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" with no info about where it's coming from except maybe some generic stuff about self invoked functions...